# Webflux Mono - Keep running to completion

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a function which does a bunch of stuff and ultimately returns a `Mono`.

If I have a handler like this:

```
fun handleSomething(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
  return longRunningMethod().flatMap {
    ServerResponse.ok.build()
  }
}
```

That will work, but it won't return the response until it finishes the long running method.

What I would like to do instead is kick off the long running method, but return a response immediately, something like this:

```
fun handleSomething(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
  longRunningMethod()

  return ServerResponse.ok.build()
}
```

Problem with this, is as soon as the response is sent (which is basically immediately), it seems like it just aborts the `longRunningMethod()`.

Is there a way to keep the `longRunningMethod()` running until it actually completes, even if the request as finished?

Comment: what is that longRunningMethod doing? How is your application supposed to behave if it fails (is the response status still valid)? Is that longRunningMethod reading the request in any form?

Comment: It  doesn't really read anything from the request (other than a queryParam). Anything to read out will be read and sent in to `longRunningMethod()` as parameters before sending the response. It is essentially a report that takes a long time to generate. Subsequent different requests would have to deal with retrieving the generated data. A `200` in this case simply means it was initiated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure, because we're missing a lot of context here.

But I think that task (which seems to be generating a report) is not strictly linked with the Controller and this might not belong here. Instead, you could send an application event from your controller and let the event listener process it.

By default, events are handled in the current thread, so you have to make sure to configure an `Executor` with that `ApplicationEventMulticaster`. In the end, it doesn't seem to matter if the report is produced or not, from the HTTP perspective, so you can decouple them completely.

In theory, you could do `longRunningMethod().subscribe()`, but it doesn't feel right to have that side effect running from the controller, with no checks. And it would also be harder to test.